# Redirection to the original site after purchase is completed in Paypal

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal, integration

I'm making one web app. I've integrated Paypal in it using simple form submission to the Paypal site. Everything works well. but whenever the payment gets successful it should redirect back to my original site with the response from Paypal. However, it's not working as it should be. Currently it stays on the Paypal site only.

```
<form action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' name='form'>
 <input type='hidden' name='business' value='<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' id='item_name' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' id='item_number' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='amount' id='amount' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://yoursite.com/cancel.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://mysite.com/user_credits/purchase_credits'>
<input type="image" src="https://paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit">
```

what am I missing in it? I'm using CakePHP 2.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to enable auto return functionality setting in paypal .

Just follow the below steps to enable

1. Log in and click the Profile subtab under My Account.
2. Click the Website Payment Preferences link under Selling Preferences.
3. Click the On radio button to enable Auto Return.
4. Enter the Return URL. Note: You must meet the Return URL requirements in order to set up Auto Return. Learn more about Return URL.

For sandbox account do the following

1. Log in to the Sandbox Merchant Id and click the Profile subtab under My Account.
2. Click the More Option link under Profile.
3. Look Selling Preferences which is third row.
4. Click the Website Payment Preferences link under Selling Preferences
5. Click the On radio button to enable Auto Return.
6. Click the On radio button to enable Auto Return.
7. Enter the Return URL. Note: You must meet the Return URL requirements in order to set up Auto Return. Learn more about Return URL.

Comment: I'm using Sandbox account for Paypal testing. I can't find the above links in my account.

Comment: Now i added the steps for Sanbox Account too... Look at that

Answer (score 1):

According to [the spec](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) for PayPal button parameters, you need to set the return method.

```
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://mysite.com/user_credits/purchase_credits'>
<input type='hidden' name='rm' value='1'>
```

The values are as follows:

- `0` - Don't redirect, and use GET.
- `1` - Automatically redirect to the `return` URL using GET.
- `2` - Automatically redirect to the `return` URL using POST, including all payment variables.

Answer (score 0):

For implement PayPal button html form parameters, use this

```
<form method=post action=https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp>
  <input type=hidden name=USER value=API_username>
  <input type=hidden name=PWD value=API_password>
  <input type=hidden name=SIGNATURE value=API_signature>
  <input type=hidden name=VERSION value=XX.0>
  <input type=hidden name=PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION value=Sale>
  <input name=PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT value=19.95>
  <input type=hidden name=RETURNURL value=https://www.YourReturnURL.com>
  <input type=hidden name=CANCELURL value=https://www.YourCancelURL.com>
  <input type=submit name=METHOD value=SetExpressCheckout>
</form>
```

This page contains all the information you need
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/

Or use the integration wizard to generate de form
https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/main.php