# PayPal doesn't redirect back to my site after purchase ends?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I read about this [Redirection to the original site after purchase is completed in Paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536393/redirection-to-the-original-site-after-purchase-is-completed-in-paypal)

And tried it - in both my sandbox account and the original one - but it doesn't seem to work.
I wrote a test message to check whether the purchase worked (in my return url) - but it still isn't working.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sell@site.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="150">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="ILS">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.myurl.com/confirm.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.myurl.com/cancel.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="01234122">
            <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/he_IL/IL/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - הדרך הקלה והבטוחה לשלם באופן מקוון!">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake - the bussines value was the orginal store and not the sandbox one

Answer (score 0):

When paying as the buyer are you paying with a PayPal account or a credit card?  The atuo return will only work if the buyer pays with a PayPal account.  If the buyer pays with a credit card, the buyer will have to click a link to return back to your site.

Comment: At this time im still using the sandbox account and user - im logging in to sandbox account (after clicking on PayNow button in my site) then clicking the 'Pay Now' button in paypal payment interface - i think this should be count as buying via paypal account....

as i said ive configured the Auto Return url in both paypal and sandbox accounts (in the profile->web payment setting) to the page i want it to redirect....

Maybe there is some issue with the cookies?? or the redirected page headers???

Comment: What is the email address of the test sandbox seller account that you are using?