# Codeigniter paypal_lib after payment redirect to success page not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

This is some hidden tag in my paypal form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="http://localhost.vma/invoice/payment_success/13183" name="return">
<input type="hidden" value="http://localhost.vma/invoice/payment_cancel/13183" name="cancel_return">
<input type="hidden" value="http://localhost.vma/invoice/payment_validate/13183" name="notify_url">
```

The problem is that after paying in paypal(sandbox) it is not redirecting back to my success my page. I don't want to be strictly that the user needs to click the return link , I don't want this to happen.

I don't know why it is not working. Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't think the code you provided is relevant. Your form is calling a controller on submit, in your controller will be logic, something like if(success) else... In here you can put your `redirect()`

Comment: Hi @Kolby, this form is a bridge on how my page and paypal communicates. I am experiencing problem same on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536393/redirection-to-the-original-site-after-purchase-is-completed-in-paypal . But I cannot find the setup that was mentioned here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will only automatically redirect in case the buyer was a registered PayPal user. Whereas for guest users, we would give them the ability to write / save the transaction receipt.

Be that as it may; for your purpose I would strongly discourage you from relying on someone reaching the return URL as a means of determining whether they completed a transaction.

1. It's not secure. If you're sending that data unencrypted to the client (browser), any buyer can figure it out and manually navigate to that URL, thus defrauding you of sales
2. It's not robust. Buyers can close their browser, not wait to return, be a guest buyer, etc.

We have a product called 'Instant Payment Notification' which addresses exactly this problem; you want a notification on your site / server that a transaction has been completed, and you would ideally like to passing this data through the client.

I suggest you take a look at the [PayPal developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/), as I'm fairly certain IPN will address your problem.

By the way, here are our [code samples](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples). [Here is one for vanilla PHP](https://github.com/robglas/paypal-ipn-sample), and [here is a CI lib](https://github.com/orderly/codeigniter-paypal-ipn), just in case.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am just starting to use paypal and thank you for the strong answer, I don't want the user think that they already paid but didn't reflect in our system. Yes I believe so IPN would be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have done all correct code. Actually after made payment with paypal they shows us payment receipts to print and after that they auto redirect on our site after 10 sec and if you want to avoid wait then they provide us back link to click.

So its paypal in-build functionality. We can't change it.

Comment: Hhmm... so every after payment the user is required to click the return back to store and it will wait for 10sec to redirect.. So there's no control on it? I was thinking maybe there's a way after payment it will redirect it in my store. And from that success, my code will stamp that it was paid..

Comment: No there is no control on paypal. It will autoredirect to given url.

Comment: After auto-redirect you can do same process. There is no problem for long time. I have used this for my couple of websites.