# Paypal automatic redirect to Store Vendor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I made a e-commerce which handles payments by Paypal, the flow works good although there is a boring thing, when the user finish to pay, to go back to the StoreWebSite has to click to the button which was provided by PayPal page. 
there is anyway to make that operation automatic?
there is any flag I can set to force paypal redirect  to my StoreWebSite when the  user finish to pay?

basically  I do that

Basically I do the following:

```
<html ng-app>
<body data-ng-controller="testController">
    <form id="Checkpay" name="Checkpay" style="margin: 0" method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_blank" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">



        <input type="hidden" id="return_url" name="return_url" value="">

        <input type="hidden" name="quantita" id="qtytext" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Le Spose di Nika">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="TEST@TEST.it">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" id="cancel_return" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" id="return" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">

        <input type="hidden" id="H_amount" name="amount" value="719.80">
        <input type="hidden" id="H_first_name" name="first_name">
        <input type="hidden" id="H_address1" name="address1">
        <input type="hidden" id="H_city" name="city">
        <input type="hidden" id="H_state" name="state">
        <input type="hidden" id="H_zip" name="zip">
        <input type="hidden" id="H_email" name="email">
        <input type="hidden" id="Country" name="country">
        <input type="hidden" id="charset" name="charset" value="utf8">
        <input type="hidden" id="rm" name="rm" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" id="notify_url" name="notify_url" value="">



        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit_post" />
    </form>
    <input id="Submit2" type="button" data-ng-click='pay()' value="js_post" />

</body>



</html>

<script src="http://localhost:27433/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:27433/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:27433/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>

    function test() {

    }

    function testController($scope, $http) {
        var URL = "http://backend.MYSITE.com/";

        $scope.payTest = function () { 

            var PAYPAL_URL_RELEASE = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"; 
            $('#return_url').val(URL);
            $('#cancel_return').val(URL + '/ErrorPay');
            $('#return').val(URL + '/Success');
            $('#notify_url').val(URL + '/PayPalReceiverIPN.ashx?idOrder=');
            document.forms["Checkpay"].action = PAYPAL_URL_RELEASE;

            document.forms["Checkpay"].submit(); 
        } 

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return_url
```

The URL to which the sender's browser is redirected after approving a payment on paypal.com.

You can find it [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/)

Comment: very strange, and does notify_url and cancel_url works?

Comment: try to write the value by yourself in return_url field...and see if it works....might be javascript problem

Comment: I think the answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536393/redirection-to-the-original-site-after-purchase-is-completed-in-paypal

Basically I need make a setting on the PayPal account to say to use  return url but unfortunatelly i cannot manage that PayPal account  which recieve  payments.. 
anyway
thanks